# How do I get the "clouds" view back in Sonar?

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

We have a Java project, which gets built by a Jenkins job and is then analyzed by Sonar.

We used to have a view within the Sonar part of the Jenkins build results called "Clouds", which showed the complexity of a class versus its test coverage, which was a very useful metric. (See [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/sonar-code-quality/9781849517867/ch10s05.html) for an example)

But now - I assume after some updates which were made to Sonar/Jenkins - it is not longer available. Can someone tell me how to get it back?

[We use SonarQube 4.5.4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is now a dedicated widget called "Project File Word Cloud" that you can add on one of your dashboards in SonarQube.

[image]